# Replacing selected shapes with symbols in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, symbols

I have these rectangles placed at different places on the file to indicate bus stands. I want to now replace each one of these rectangles with a bus symbol.

How do I do that without dragging the symbol to each place, deleting the rectangle, and making sure that the symbol is in the "bus stand" sub layer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great script that does exactly what you want.

It was written by @Loic Aigon, it's called [SymbolReplacement](https://www.scriptopedia.org/en/js-illustrator/24-symbolreplacement-en.html) and will cost you only a Thank you Email ^^

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You really can't.

There's no internal method of replacing an object with any other object, symbol or otherwise. The only "replacement" features in Illustrator relate to replacing symbols with *other symbols* or replacing linked assets.

So.. a round about way.....

Drag each Rectangle to the Symbols Panel to make them a symbol. Then use the **Replace** option in the **Control Bar** to replace the rectangle symbol with another symbol. Then you could delete the rectangle symbol if you'd like.

[image]

I'm not really sure that method is any better than....

Drag the bus symbol from the Symbols Panel, and then use the existing rectangle as a **Key Object** for alignment. Then delete the rectangle.